# How do I redirect all URLs to a specific URL in HAProxy?

Tags: redirect, haproxy

How do I redirect all URLs to one URL in HAProxy?

If the URL is anything other than `www.mysite.com`, it should redirect to `www.mysite.com`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
acl example hdr_dom(host) -i www.example.com
use_backend example_backend if example
```

```
backend example_backend
 mode http 
 option httpchk OPTION /
 option  redispatch
 option httpclose
 option forwardfor
 balance roundrobin
 server example.com 10.200.1.47:80   maxconn 500
```

Hope this resolves !!!

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you

```
# mysite.com
 acl is_mysite hdr_end(host) -i www.mysite.com
 use_backend srv_mysite if is_mysite

# All otherserver
 default_backend srv_othersite
```

```
backend srv_mysite
 balance roundrobin
 cookie SERVERID insert nocache indirect
 option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
 option httpclose
 option forwardfor
 server Local 192.168.10.32:80 cookie Local

backend srv_othersite
 balance roundrobin
 cookie SERVERID insert nocache indirect
 option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
 option httpclose
 option forwardfor
 server Local 192.168.10.40:80 cookie Local
```

This will redirect user asking for `www.mysite.com` to `192.168.10.32` and all other request to `192.168.10.40`